# Nginx редирект на статичные страницы

Tags: nginx

Подскажите как сделать ридерект на определенные страницы
Есть сайт , есть nginx
Настройки nginx

```
location / {

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
                try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

    }
```

Сайт на ajax - то есть все запросы идут на index.html, а там уже js обрабатывает хэш и выдает определенное содержимое.

Есть php файл для отправки на почту

Если запрос вида http://site.ru/prices?_escaped_fragment_= то отдается страничка их опреденной директории , например /static/prices.html

http://site.ru/about?_escaped_fragment_=  - /static/about.html

Как написать эти исключение если уже есть настройка

```
location / {
                    try_files $uri /index.html;
            }
```

Можно просто хардкодом на каждую страницу свой location

Не могу использовать rewrite тк в начальной сборке nginx его нету, а пересобирать nginx нет возможности

```
server {                                                                                                        
        server_name site.ru www.site.ru;                                                                
        charset off;                                                                                            
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;                                                          
        index index.html;                                                                                       
        root $root_path;                                                                                        
        set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru;                                                      
        access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.access.log ;                                                 
        error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log notice;                                             
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;                                                              
        gzip on;                                                                                                
        gzip_disable "msie6";                                                                                   
        gzip_types                                                                                              
                application/atom+xml                                                                            
                application/javascript                                                                          
                application/json                                                                                
                application/rss+xml                                                                             
                application/vnd.ms-fontobject                                                                   
                application/x-font-ttf                                                                          
                application/x-web-app-manifest+json                                                             
                application/xhtml+xml                                                                           
                application/xml                                                                                 
                font/opentype                                                                                   
                image/svg+xml                                                                                   
                image/x-icon                                                                                    
                image/png                                                                                       
                image/gif                                                                                       
                image/jpeg                                                                                      
                image/jpg                                                                                       
                text/css                                                                                        
                text/plain                                                                                      
                text/x-component;                                                                               

        location /about$ {                                                                                          

        if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {                                                                    
            set $args "";                                                                                       

            rewrite ^/.* http://yandex.ru permanent;                                                            
        }                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                           

        location /prices$ {                                                                                         
        if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {                                                                    
            set $args "";                                                                                       
            rewrite ^/.* http://yandex.ru permanent;                                                            
        }                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                           

        location / {                                                                                            

        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {                                                                        
                try_files /does_not_exists @php;                                                                
        }                                                                                                       

            location / {                                                                                        
                try_files $uri /index.html;                                                                     
        }                                                                                                       

        }                                                                                                           

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff)$ {            
            expires 30d;                                                                                    
            etag on;                                                                                        
        }                                                                                                       


    location @fallback {                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                       

        location @php {                                                                                         

                fastcgi_index index.php;                                                                        
                fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site.ru
";                                                                                                              
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;                                                   
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;                                       
                try_files $uri =404;                                                                            
                include fastcgi_params;                                                                         
        }                                                                                                       
        ssi on;                                                                                                 
        listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;                                                                               
}
```

Comment: С чего это его нет? Rewrite есть в стандартной сборке nginx, если качать с их сайта.

Comment: ну падает nginx если пишу директиву эту

Comment: Значит, сборка нестандартная или пишете неправильно

Comment: Вывел все модули nginx в вопросе, если учесть что сборка не стандартная что можно сделать

Comment: В конфиге nginx отсутствует –without-http_rewrite_module, а значит, он есть. Покажите, где и как вы пишите rewrite, после чего nginx падает. Да, и что он выводит после вставки инструкции rewrite по команде nginx -t ?

Comment: И так и непонятно из вопроса, что на что надо переадресовать. Напишите ссылку-источник и ссылку-желаемый_результат.

Comment: http://site.ru/about?_escaped_fragment_=     -> http://site.ru//static/about.html

Comment: site.ru/prices?_escaped_fragment_= -> site.ru//static/prices.html

Comment: Возможно я неправильно пишу инструкции, можете привести пример, но только чтобы он не конфликтовал с уже имеющимися настройками location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставьте такой код внутри секции server перед вашей location, указанной в примере:

```
# site.ru/about?_escaped_fragment_= -> site.ru/static/about.html    
location /about$ {
    if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $args "";
        rewrite ^/.* http://site.ru/static/about.html permanent;
    }
}       

# site.ru/prices?_escaped_fragment_= -> site.ru/static/prices.html  
location /prices$ {
    if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $args "";
        rewrite ^/.* http://site.ru/static/prices.html permanent;
    }
}
```

Вот полная секция server, в соответствии с добавленным вопрос кодом:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name so-665808.kagg.eu;
    charset off;
    set $root_path /var/www/so-665808;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    root $root_path;
    index index.html;

    #access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.access.log;
    #error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/site.ru.error.log notice;
    #include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon image/png image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg text/css text/plain text/x-component;

    location ~* /about {
        if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $args "";
            rewrite ^/.* http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/about.html permanent;
        }
    }

    location ~* /prices {
        if ($args ~* "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $args "";
            rewrite ^/.* http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/prices.html permanent;
        }
    }

    location / {
        location ~ [^/]\.ph(p\d*|tml)$ {
            try_files /does_not_exists @php;
        }
        location / {                                                                                        
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf|woff)$ {
        expires 30d;
        etag on;
    }

    location @fallback {
    }

    location @php {                                                                                         
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@site.ru";                                                                                                              
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/php-fpm/user.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.ph(?:p\d*|tml))(/?.+)$;
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }   

    ssi on;
}
```

Закомментированы строчки с логами, потому что у меня нет таких папок, да и не влияет это ни на что. Закомментирован `include  /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;` - я не знаю, что там.

Мой код выше изменен совсем немного (только в части указания location) - он работал на тестовом сайте WordPress, а там еще и свои редиректы.

Для теста создан специальный сайт `so-665808.kagg.eu`. В нём три файла:

```
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/index.html
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/about.html
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/prices.html
```

При вводе адреса

```
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/about?_escaped_fragment_
```

происходит переход на

```
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/about.html
```

При вводе адреса

```
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/prices?_escaped_fragment_
```

происходит переход на

```
http://so-665808.kagg.eu/static/prices.html
```

Проверьте.

Comment: не работает, ощущение что он не заходит в if, то есть мне отлается страница index.html

Comment: Я не знаю, что там еще у вас в настройках nginx. Я проверял у себя на тестовом сайте - работает. Код не из головы, а оттестирован.

Comment: выложил полный файл, можно как то продебажить заходит ли он в данный location?

Comment: Что браузер отдает при вводе `site.ru/about?_escaped_fragment_=` ?

Comment: Index.html отдает

Comment: а что у вас тут  include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;

Comment: Обязательно проверю, Скажите а можно ли использовать try_files вместо rewrite?, не знаю как поисковики отнесутся к тому, что происходит редирект и url меняется. В случае  try_files просто отдается нужный контент и url не меняется

Comment: Ну, это уже другой вопрос, наверное. Этот вопрос был про rewrite

Comment: Ну впринципе это же реально?

Comment: Наверное, надо заниматься и проверять

Comment: работает  с rewrite